VS2019 build failure - Can’t find windows.h
I have a number vs2019 projects that I have built successfully in the past.
Recently I have encountered the subject issue with one of these, named ThisIsMostCertainlyTrue.
An attempt to build either the Win32 Debug or Win32 Release version of the executable fails, issuing the following error message:
Build started... 
1>------ Build started: Project: ThisIsMostCertainlyTrue, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------ 
1>C:\My Documents\Rob\AppsForWin_vs2019\_GENERIC\GenericCodeResources\GenericMenuDefines.h(30): 
fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'windows.h'. 
1> 
1>Done building project "ThisIsMostCertainlyTrue.vcxproj" -- FAILED. 
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ========== 

This problem is strictly repeatable.
All component source files compile successfully, both individually and as part of the build attempt.
None of my other vs2019 projects exhibits this problem.
All possible permutations of the listed REMEDIES ATTEMPTED have been performed, all w/o success.
REMEDIES ATTEMPTED:
Clean solution.
Attempt to rebuild both Win32 Debug and Win32 Release versions of the subject project.
Reboot PC.
Close and reopen vs2019 IDE.
Recreate from scratch a duplicate version of the subject project.
Reinstall vs2019 Community.
Verify that other projects on my PC do NOT have this problem.
Manually compare all IDE project property settings on ThisIsMostCertainlyTrue against those of another one of my projects to verify that all non-project-specific properties are identical.

open a DOS command window and do DIR windows.h /s/p  and then compare where it is found with the search paths that the compiler is using. Tack -v /Qsox onto the compiler command line and you might get to see enough extra guff to make sense of what is happening.

Thanks for your advice.  I did DIR windows.h /s/p and found directory c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um, which I promptly added to Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories.   Unfortunately, this action did not reslve the issue.  Also, I compile and build within the  IDE and haven't a clue as to how to build via a command line.  I could not find any site within the IDE to specify the Tack -v /Qsox option.

I was trying to reproduce your issue but I cannot repro it.Can you share more detail about your project and check if there is any other project which used windows.h header and is having the same issue?

On mine it is in "Project Properties |>  Config |> C/C++|>Command Line and at the bottom there is an option to add any other options you like. Additional options -v /Qsox goes there and should show you all the gory details in the Build window (from the dropdown list that usually shows "Debug").

Adding "-v /Qsox" as an Additional Option under Configuration Properties -> Resources -> Command Line resulted in the following error msg thrown by Build:
1>------ Build started: Project: ThisIsMostCertainlyTrue, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------

1>RC : fatal error RC1107: invalid usage; use RC /? for Help 

1>                                                   

1>Done building project "ThisIsMostCertainlyTrue.vcxproj" -- FAILED. 

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========


Afraid they apparently don't apply to the MSC native C/C++ compiler but do work for the Intel ICX compiler (although not for its linker). The output is somewhat verbose. On MSVC 2022 it doesn't error merely ignores the command line parameters it doesn't like. I think you can install ICX on 2019 and swap between them. It can be enlightening - ICX often (but not always) generates faster numerical code with the right options.

If you could post the actual .vcxproj somewhere, we might be able to help.

I have resolved the issue, the solution for which was embarrassingly simple.
The culprit was an #include statement in the relevant *.rc file which referenced windows.h.  Deleting same eliminated the error.
My thanks to all who responded to this question.
